# How can I make it so once a user submits on a google forum it executes a function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google forum that links to a spreadsheet and my code is linked to the spreadsheet. I want to make it so once a user submits on the forum and the spreadsheet receives a change it executes a function. What would be the simplest and most efficient way of doing so?

Comment: `onFormSubmit()` trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an [event trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) in the Apps Script file of your Google Form or Google Sheet is the way to do it. With this, each time a Google Form submission is made your function will run.

Here is an example when creating it in your Google Form:

- Open your Google Form
- Open the Script Editor
- Create the following function

```
function onFormSubmit(e){

    var response = e.response;

    var responseId = response.getId();

    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

    var formResponse = form.getResponse(responseId);

    // enter the rest of your code here that you would like to run each time a form submission is made

}
```

- Then, within your Script Editor file, click **Edit** > **Current project's triggers**
- In the bottom right corner, click **Add trigger**
- Select the onFormSubmit function, change the event type to 'On form submit', and leave everything else as they default
- Next form submission that is made, your function will run.

Hope this helps.

---

Comment: thank you so much you :) this is my first time using appscript and this helped me a lot.